# Replace A Hashtag With A LI Element

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, insert

I Have A Quick Goal. For example, I have this text:

```
# Text I Want to Be Inserted Into An Element
```

this is would I would like to achieve:

```
<li>Text I want to Be inserted Into An Element</li>
```

Any javascript code to do this such as:

```
var text =  "# Text I Want to Be Inserted Into An Element"
```

right now I have this:

```
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('GET', "ColeRubins.md", false);
xmlhttp.send();
var fcn = xmlhttp.responseText
document.write(fcn);
```

Comment: Shoud `<li>Text I want to Be inserted Into An Element</li>` be a string or an HTMLElement?

Comment: Html element...

Comment: Like as in `document.createElement`? Because you can't have that in node or express

Comment: And what about multiple lines? Or will it be only one?

Comment: I am trying to turn a MD file into a variable but each line can be into a bullet point.

Comment: Take a look at the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex for this.

```js
var text =  "# Text I Want to Be Inserted Into An Element"
text = text.replace(/^#\s+(.*)$/gm, '<li>$1</li>')
console.log(text) // '<li>Text I Want to Be Inserted Into An Element</li>'
```

Explanation:

- `^` Matches the start of the line
- `\s+` Matches one or more whitespace characters
- `(.*)` Matches any character 0-Infinity times
- `$` Matches end of line
- Flags:

  - `g` Global, match all matches
  - `m` Multiline, match more than one line, `^` is start and `$` is end

Comment: Thank You So Much!

Comment: @AsherMyers If this helped you, can you [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclaimer:

Since you do not have a character to signify the closing tag, I will assume you want to add it to the end.

#### Steps:

First, you need to check if the string contains your character at the first index. Only then run your code.

Second, you need to remove the first character of the string.

(The reason for not simply deleting the special character if it exists at any point, is to allow that special character to reappear later in the string.)

Third, you need to add the first "<li>" tag. Just prepend this by concatenating your string to "<li>"

Third, append the closing "<\li>"

#### The code

```
const addLITagsToStringAndRemoveHashtag = (str, specialCharacter = "#") => {
    if(str.charAt(0) === specialCharacter) {
        return `<li>${str.substring(1, str.length)}</li>`;
    }
}
```